# Splitting Hibernate-mapped program into front-end and back-end using Spring Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, spring, hibernate, soap

I planning to split my systems into front-end and back-end. Currently my application directly communicates with database, but I want to create a Spring Web service to do it instead. My problem lies with using Hibernate to map my objects to database tables.

I need my front end program to have persistant up-to-date interaction with the database. This again means I have to write a lot of web service endpoints to handle all the queries and updates. This again makes it Hibernate mapping pointless, since I'm not gaining anything.

My question is: is there a proven and reasonable way to pass (via SOAP if possible) hibernate mapped objects over to front-end and later commit changes done to these objects?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Quick critique, I think you might be taking reuse a step to far. A better way to achieve this is to put your domain objects in a jar and use that domain jar for access to database. through your hibernate domain. This way your webservice endpoints can be used for modeling business services that use the hibernate domain for their data access. If you are using something like Maven many projects can share the domain jar as a dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: no.

Detaching and re-attaching hibernate-managed objects in different applications, like you are thinking of, will lead to all kinds of problems that you want to avoid, such as concurrency and locking issues, after you've dealt with all the LazyLoadingExceptions. It will be a pain in the b***.

The road you're heading into finally leads to an architecture that adds an extra layer of indirection with [Data Objects](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) being transferred between business service and clients of those business services. Only your business service will be able to talk to the database directly. Obviously this time-consuming, and must be avoided if possible. That's why I asked you to explain the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: this sort of architecture is a symptom of too many 'architects', 'consultants' and too much politics....very rarely do real devs decide on such needless gymnastics

Comment: @HansWesterbeek Sorry for the delay in my answering. My problem lies with minimizing work-hours spent on this. I have a database with rather extensive schema to manage. That's why hibernate was chosen to map it. Right now I have all the business logic on the client side (including communication with database and it's verification) as a Java application. For security reasons I have to shift a lot of it to the back-end. The problem is that, by doing this I kind of find myself having to rewrite all the services. I am looking to find a abstraction to get around it.

Comment: i see... in that case, you will end up with the architecture i described, exposing objects and properties on 'need to know' basis to the client in specific usecases.

Also, consider using REST/JSON instead of SOAP, that may save you some time.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass hibernated entities via SOAP or other serialization mechanisms,   but you shall be very careful  with lazy loading, collections loading and detaching entities from session - otherwise you may end up sending all your database where you need just one object or hibernate proxies which are not usable on the other side.